# What's the difference between 'part of' and 'a part of '？

Tags: meaning, phrases

I usually see these sentences containing 'part of' or 'a part of' ,like

1.An apartment or compartment is part of a larger whole.

2.He spends at least a part of his time in reading.

What's the difference beween them, and how to use them in different conditions? Thanks a lot.

Comment: In 2, I think "some part of" is more correct than "a part of". Maybe you want to replace your example with the sentence "This is a part of city where you can find lots of bookstores."

Answer (score 1):

**Part of** means part of something, i.e, it is less than the whole object, but **a part of** means little bit of something, i.e., a specific sub unit of the object.